# How does return work within a Monad context within Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, return, monads, return-type

Why does the following, given that the RegModule instance defines its return as: `return a = RegModule (\_s _i d -> return (a, 0, d))`, not return `[((c, i+1, d), Int, d)]`, and why does the second case expression not need to be written with `return []`:

```
scanChar :: RegModule d Char
scanChar = RegModule (\s i d ->
  case drop i s of
    (c:cs) -> return (c, i+1, d)
    [] -> []
  )
```

In MVE:

```
import qualified Data.Set as S

import Control.Monad

type CharSet = S.Set Char

data RE =
    RClass Bool CharSet

newtype RegModule d a =
  RegModule {runRegModule :: String -> Int -> d -> [(a, Int, d)]}

instance Monad (RegModule d) where
  return a = RegModule (\_s _i d -> return (a, 0, d))
  m >>= f =
    RegModule (\s i d -> do (a, j, d') <- runRegModule m s i d
                            (b, j', d'') <- runRegModule (f a) s (i + j) d'
                            return (b, j + j', d''))

instance Functor (RegModule d) where fmap = liftM
instance Applicative (RegModule d) where pure = return; (<*>) = ap

scanChar :: RegModule d Char
scanChar = RegModule (\s i d ->
  case drop i s of
    (c:cs) -> return (c, i+1, d)
    [] -> []
  )

regfail :: RegModule d a
regfail = RegModule (\_s _i d -> []
                )
regEX :: RE -> RegModule [String] ()
regEX (RClass b cs) = do
  next <- scanChar  
  if (S.member next cs)
    then return ()
    else regfail
 
runRegModuleThrice :: RegModule d a -> String -> Int -> d -> [(a, Int, d)]
runRegModuleThrice matcher input startPos state =
  let (result1, pos1, newState1) = head $ runRegModule matcher input startPos state
      (result2, pos2, newState2) = head $ runRegModule matcher input pos1 newState1
      (result3, pos3, newState3) = head $ runRegModule matcher input pos2 newState2
  in [(result1, pos1, newState1), (result2, pos2, newState2), (result3, pos3, newState3)]
```

Comment: your `return` does not use the `instance Monad (RegModule d)`, it uses `instance Monad []`, the list, so `return` wraps the value into a list.

Comment: You mean that this `return (c, i+1, d)` uses the `instance Monad []` ? In that case how does it know to use `instance Monad []` rather than the `instance Monad (RegModule d)` , which also has a `return a` function ?

Comment: Because of type inference: to make `RegModule (\s i d -> ...)` type check, it's required that `...` has type `[(a, Int, d)]`. So both case branches `return (c, i+1, d)` and `[]` must have such type. This in turn triggers the selection of the `Monad []` instance for the `return`.

Comment: @Piskator `return` always uses the type it's expected to produce to determine which `Monad` instance to use. In this case `return (c, i+1, d)` doesn't appear in a context where it's supposed to produce a `RegModule`, because it is used **inside** the `RegModule` constructor. The `RegModule` constructor takes a `String -> Int -> d -> [(a, Int, d)]` function, and `return` is being used to produce the list return value of such a function (the `\s i d ->` part earlier has already taken care of putting us inside a function taking the 3 parameters).

Comment: @Piskator: yes, `return (c, i+1, d)` in this context is just `[(c, i+1, d)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of type inference.  In the code:

```
scanChar :: RegModule d Char
scanChar = RegModule (\s i d ->
  case drop i s of
    (c:cs) -> return (c, i+1, d)
    [] -> []
  )
```

the `RegModule` constructor on the right hand side has type:

```
RegModule :: (String -> Int -> d -> [(a, Int, d)]) -> RegModule d a
```

Since `scanChar` has type signature `RegModule d Char`, Haskell unifies the types `RegModule d Char` (on the left) with `RegModule d a` (on the right), resulting in the unification of the type variable `a` with `Char`.  Therefore, the expected type of the function passed to the `RegModule` constructor is:

```
String -> Int -> d -> [(Char, Int, d)]
```

Note that, so far, we've only considered the type signature for `scanChar`, and the type of the constructor `RegModule`.  Nothing from the various instances for `RegModule` has been used.

Anyway, the anonymous lambda `\s i d -> ...` gets unified with this type, so the arguments `s`, `i`, and `d` must have type `String`, `Int`, and `d` respectively, as you'd expect from their names, while the body must have type `[(Char, Int, d)]`.  Since the body of the anonymous lambda is a `case` expression, every expression on the right-hand side of one of the cases must have that same type, `[(Char, Int, d)]`.  So, we have:

```
return (c, i+1, d) :: [(Char, Int, d)]  -- for the first case
```

and:

```
[] :: [(Char, Int, d)]                  -- for the second case
```

The `return` function is polymorphic with type `(Monad m) => t -> m t`, so to unify this particular `return` expression with its type, Haskell unifies `m` with the list functor `[]` and `t` with the type of the argument passed to `(c, i+1, d)`, namely `(Char, Int, d)`.  This instantiates `return` to the type for the `[]` monad:

```
return :: t -> [t]
```

and the list for elements of type `(Char, Int, d)` in particular:

```
return :: (Char, Int, d) -> [(Char, Int, d)]
```

So, it's the `return` function for the list monad that's used, and -- given its definition -- you could replace the code with:

```
...
(c:cs) -> [(c, i+1, d)]
...
```

and it would have the same meaning.

On the other hand, if the `[]` on the RHS of the last case was replaced with `return []`, the compiler would attempt to unify the general type signature for `return`:

```
return :: (Monad m) => t -> m t
```

by unifying the argument type `t` with the type of the empty list `[] :: [u]` giving the type equality:

```
t ~ [u]
```

for some `u`, while at the same type unifying the type of the `return []` expression `m t` with the expected type based on the type inference above, namely `[(Char, Int, d)]`, giving the type equalities:

```
m ~ []
t ~ (Char, Int, d)
```

Since the type equality `t ~ [u]` is incompatible with the type equality `t ~ (Char, Int, d)`, this would be a type error:

```
Return.hs:29:18-19: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type: (Char, Int, d)
                  with actual type: [a0]
```

In the end, none of the type inference above uses the type of `return` for `RegModule d` monad.